# Is there a default route in case of any invalid url in django?

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I am not an expert on Django. I came across for the invalid url a lot in django. is there any defualt route to be configured instead of showing nothing or showing error page while debuging.
like, we might configure one route that redirects in any case of invalid url or not data found or ...
Hope i explained and made my point clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the updates, I have created a invalid url response, in case of any errors,  re redirect to that url. It works as it should be. problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You could look to custom error pages:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

This way in your views you can still raise 404 exceptions that will be handled correctly